# Slider similar to kiwks control in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am fairly new to HTML and Javascript. I need to create a page as the following http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_37383/index-4.html

I dont want to use a plugin and am trying to create it on my own.

Below is the code I came up with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 

#div1
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:gray;
    transition:width 2s;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s; /* Safari */
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid;
}

#div1:hover
{
    width:300px;
}

#div2
{
    width: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    -moz-transform:    rotate(-90deg);            
    -ms-transform:     rotate(-90deg);            
    -o-transform:      rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

#div3
{
    background:red;
    float: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1">
      <Table style="width:100%;height:100%">
        <col width="20">
        <col width="120">
        <td>
            <div id="div2"> HELLO </div>
        </td>
        <td>
        <ul>
            <li> Text 1 </li>
            <li> Text 2 </li>
        </ul>
        </td>
    </table>     
</div>

<div id ="div3"></div>
<div id="div1">
<ul>
<li>checking 1 </li>
<li> checking 2 </li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am facing two issues in this,
I am not able to place the red div block to the left end as shown in the other link. I want the text to be hidden when that div collapses.

http://jsfiddle.net/dipz_26/e9mvS/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is known as Accordion Navigation try searching for that style and see what tutorials you can come up with.

If you wanted to use a click to expand the tab, I would recommend watching out for hijacking the back button. Personally, I don't like navigation hijacking the back button if you never really switch files, especially if it is used within a page that already has navigation links. but again, this is just what I think about it.

Best Of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Did some quick firebugging - getting red title box to align properly seems pretty tricky ( maybe because of table element not formed correctly? )

Below code is not really an answer to your problem ( as in why are you getting that weired behaviour ) but rather another approach to solve the same problem:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/e9mvS/2/

The deal is to resuse classes as much as possible:

HTML:

```
<div class="awesome-thing">
    <div class="awesome-thing-section">
        <div class="awesome-thing-header">
            Some title
        </div>
        <div class="awesome-thing-body">
            <ul>
                <li>checking 1 </li>
                <li> checking 2 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="awesome-thing-section">
        <div class="awesome-thing-header">
            Some title 2
        </div>
        <div class="awesome-thing-body">
            <ul>
                <li>checking 1 </li>
                <li> checking 2 </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.awesome-thing {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.awesome-thing-section {
     width:100px;
     height:300px;
     background:gray;
     border: 2px solid;
     position:relative;
     float:left;
     transition:width 2s ease;
     overflow:hidden;
}



.awesome-thing-header {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:100px;

    -moz-transform:    rotate(-90deg);            
    -ms-transform:     rotate(-90deg);            
    -o-transform:      rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

    transform-origin: center 150px 0;
    background:red;
}

.awesome-thing-body {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:100px;
    width:200px;
    opacity:0;
    transition:opacity 2s ease;
}

.awesome-thing-section:hover {
    width:300px;
}
.awesome-thing-section:hover .awesome-thing-body {
    opacity:1;
}
```